# What is nixio.getenv() in openwrt

Tags: lua, openwrt, getenv

I am new to openwrt, I am using Lua on uhttpd on OpenWRT. Please help me to understand nixio.getenv().
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: `nixio.getenv([variable])` returns environment table or single environment variable (if optional argument `variable` specified)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff What is environment table and what are the contents in it?

Comment: I guess environment table contains environment variables such as `$PATH`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for your help.